# Contact form with AJAX not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I work on a Wordpress website and I'm trying to create a form (with an ajax call) which apears on every's product pages. I've tried it on other servers, worked very nice, but when I integrate my code in a Wordpress page is not working. I'm using Woocomerce so the php file I'm trying to modify is "content-single-product.php"

My code:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
      
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 
           
         var proceed = true;
            //simple validation at client's end
            //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields  
      $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
       $(this).css('border-color',''); 
       if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
        $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
       }
       //check invalid email
       var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
       if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
        $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag    
       } 
      });
           
            if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
            {
       //get input field values data to be sent to server
                post_data = {
        'user_email' : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
        'phone_number' : $('input[name=telefon]').val(), 
       };
                
                //Ajax post data to server
                $.post('*the path to php file*', post_data, function(response){  
        if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
         output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
        }else{
            output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
         //reset values in all input fields
         $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
         $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
        }
        $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }, 'json');
            }
        });
        
        //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
        $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            $("#result").slideUp();
        });
    });      
    </script>         
                
    <div style="padding-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" id="contact_form">
        <div id="contact_results"></div>
        <div id="contact_body">
            <div style="color:#ff0000; font-size:12px;">Title text</div>
     <p>
         <div style="color:#999999; font-size:12px;">Description text</div>
     </p>
     <label><span>Phone: </span>
                <input type="text" name="telefon" maxlength="15"  required="true" placeholder="Phone"/>
            </label>
            <label><span>E-mail: </span>
                <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field" placeholder="E-mail adress"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Order now" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the PHP code is

```js
<?php
if($_POST)
{
 $to_email    = "email@email.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
 
 //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
  
  $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
   'type'=>'error', 
   'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
  ));
  die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 
 
 //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
 $user_email  = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 $phone_number = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 $url   = filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 
 //additional php validation
 if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
  die($output);
 }
 if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
  die($output);
 }
 
 //email body
 $subject = "Client nou ! - Telefon: ". $phone_number;
 $message_body = "\r\nNumar de telefon : ". $phone_number."\r\nClientul este interesat de urmatorul produs : ". $url;
 
 //proceed with PHP email.
 $headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
 $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
 
 if(!$send_mail)
 {
  //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
  die($output);
 }else{
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => '<div style="color:#999999; font-size:12px;">The order was sent. In few moments we will contact you at the phone number <strong>'.$phone_number .'</strong>!</div>'));
  die($output);
 }
}
?>
```

I'm not so experienced with Wordpress. I have to adapt it somehow, I think. That's actually my question. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

In your code you need to add the action post data:

```
post_data = {
  'user_email'  : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
  'phone_number'    : $('input[name=telefon]').val(), 
  'action' : 'my_custom_send_mail',
  'nonce' : '<?php wp_create_nonce('mycustom_mail_form_nonce'); ?>'
};
```

Instead of `*the path to php file*` you need to call `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>`.

Then in the functions.php or the my-plugin.php you can call the function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_custom_send_mail', 'my_custom_send_mail_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_send_mail', 'my_custom_send_mail_callback' );

function my_custom_send_mail_callback(){

  if(!check_ajax_referer( 'mycustom_mail_form_nonce', 'nonce' )){
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Something went wrong!'));
    die($output);
  }

  $to_email     = "email@email.com";
  $user_email   = sanitize_email($_POST["user_email"]);
  $phone_number = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

  if(!is_email($user_email)){
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
  }
  if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
    die($output);
  }

  //email body
  $subject = "Client nou ! - Telefon: ". $phone_number;
  $message_body = "\r\nNumar de telefon : ". $phone_number."\r\nClientul este interesat de urmatorul produs : ". $url;

  //proceed with PHP email.
  $headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  $send_mail = wp_mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

  if(!$send_mail){
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
  }else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => '<div style="color:#999999; font-size:12px;">The order was sent. In few moments we will contact you at the phone number <strong>'.$phone_number .'</strong>!</div>'));
    die($output);
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, I think I'm getting closer...now the script actually behaves like a ajax but if insetad of "the path to php file" I put "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" like you said, then where will I actually write the path to my php file? Which actually sends my e-mail. Thank you !

Comment: You don't need to have an own php file. Just include your sendmail function right after the nonce has been checked. (Where I added "// your send mail function").

Comment: I added the whole function to the script.

Comment: Sorry for my absence, barely now I'm "back in business". The script is not working... After I submit, the ajax shows me "undefined", not the message I want to...